# Source files and MSBuild .proj file in different directories

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a project (currently its .csproj, containing only .js files). I only use it for some post build events, and intellisense from Visual Studio.

Can I somehow have following directory structure?

```
Root/Projects/HelloWorld.(cs)proj
Root/Sources/Test.js
```

But Visual Studio seems to take source files only from folders that are under .csproj file, if I try to add files from somewhere else, they are added as links (which I can't delete or rename from VS). Is there for example something that I can put to .proj file that would change root directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can `mklink /D Sources ..\Sources` to trick VS, but it might mess with your VCS or you can hook into `AfterBuild` target and copy Sources from VS's root up to IntelliJ.

Comment: I guess there is no platform indepndent link that could be stored in vcs, right? :) But it still could be a solution it would just require to run some .bat before you start developing which isnt so bad. Oh, so git would store the link as real files, well i could .gitignore it...

Comment: This solution works great for me. I can add the symlink to Perforce using the command `p4 add -t symlink Sources`.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio only supports two methods of adding files to a `.csproj`: either it copies the file you add somewhere under the directory hierarchy of the `.csproj` (the default) or if you choose to add the file as a link, it adds a reference to the file.

You can't change the former behavior except by invoking the latter behavior, which apparently has downsides you aren't comfortable with.

You could edit the `.csproj` directly to include additional files in the `Compile` [item group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx), which would likely build, but wouldn't display or function as you'll probably expect in the IDE itself.

If your goal is to separate source and project, you could rearrange the structure of your directories so projects all are at the root, and there's a source directory that's a sibling to those projects:

```
Foo.csproj
Foo.someotherproj
Source/
  *.js
```

This would mean you have everything in a "Source" folder in the `.csproj` when viewed from Visual Studio.

Another option might be to look at some kind of project generation tools, like [premake](http://industriousone.com/premake) or [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), but their support for C# projects files may not be that robust.

Comment: Adding them like that directly to .csproj will create links to them and doesn't show directories.

But I think I read somewhere that .vcproj can only add files as links and renaming works there, or something like that.

Comment: I want to do this because my project can be build with VS or Idea, so I dont want to mix VS specific files inside soureces. I actually dont need it to compile or anything I just need to see it in VS.